# Can someone guide me through this functional equation?

Tags: functional-equations

I'm not necessarily sure how to approach this problem—or whether it even has a solution—but I would like to know an example of a non-constant function that satisfies this condition:

$$f(x,y,z)f(x,z,y)f(y,x,z)f(y,z,x)f(z,x,y)f(z,y,x)=1$$

Also, could someone point me to a good book that can help me with these types of questions?

*edit: By the way, I really don't care how this function would look like—if it ends up being a matrix, that'll do.

Thank you all!

**Edit: I probably should clarify that the 1 means identity. I'm putting that info down because I'm not sure what the answer could be, but I would like it to refer as an identity.

Comment: Theophile, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to MSE. Here is a great [typesetting reference and tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\,f(x,y,z) := g(x y z)\,$ for some non-constant function $\,g\,$
that satisfies $\,g(x)^6 = 1\,$ then $\,f\,$ satisifes your functional equation.
There are other possibilities such as $\, f(x,y,z) := g(x\!+\!y\!+\!z),\,$ or in
general, $\,f(x,y,z) := g(h(x,y,z))\,$ where $\,h\,$ is any
[symmetric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function).

Answer (score 4):

How about the non-constant function
$$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if } x\leq 0\\-1&\text{ if }x>0\end{cases}.$$